# What's the difference between writing a file by editor like vim/nano and by output redirection in shell?

Tags: linux, kernel, macos

I am using macOS with **[SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection)** enabled. And I am figuring out why the scripts run so slowly with the SIP after a modification or creation.

And I found if I modify a script by editors like vim or nano, and run it by `./script.bash`, it will take about 1 second to finish the script for the first time after each modification.

For example.
If the script.bash is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 1
```

And I change it to below by `vim`. It takes me about ten times longer time to run it.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 1
echo 2
```

```
bash-3.2$ time ./script.bash # First time after modification by vim
1
2

real    0m0.884s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.002s
```

```
bash-3.2$ time ./script.bash # Second time after modification by vim
1
2

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.002s
```

---

While if I currently append the file by some command's output redirection like `echo "echo 3" >> script.bash` and still call the script by `./script.bash`, the delay is gone.

```
bash-3.2$ echo "echo 3" >> script.bash
bash-3.2$ time ./script.bash # First time after modification by echo
1
2
3

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.002s
bash-3.2$ time ./script.bash # Second time after modification by echo
1
2
3

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.001s
```

So what's the difference between the two ways of writing a file? And why the delay happens only with **SIP** enabled?

Comment: You probably need to expand on what "SIP" is in this context.

Comment: I can reproduce this on my mac although the delays are significantly lower.  I'm not sure SIP is related though as it shouldn't have any affect on the directory I'm working out of.

Comment: @jesse_b I am sure the delay is caused by the **SIP** by switching it multiple times. I don't know the internal details but I suspect it is because of the `exec()`, because `bash ./script.bash` executes the script smoothly. But it is really annoying when I am practising scripting, almost every modification cause a more second delay to finish. And compared to reason the why it delays, I am more curious at why the second way makes no delays. Because I think the only choice to solve the problem is disable **SIP**,lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this article](https://sigpipe.macromates.com/2020/macos-catalina-slow-by-design/) which I believe explains your issue.

> Apple has introduced notarization, setting aside the inconvenience this brings to us developers, it also results in a degraded user experience, as the first time a user runs a new executable, Apple delays execution while waiting for a reply from their server. This check for me takes close to a second.

> This is not just for files downloaded from the internet, nor is it only when you launch them via Finder, this is everything. So even if you write a one line shell script and run it in a terminal, you will get a delay!

> As for the notarization check, the result is cached, so second invocation should be fast, but if you are a developer, you may update your scripts and binaries regularly, which trigger new checks (it appears caching is based on inode, so an update-in-place save may avoid triggering a new check), or you may have workflows that involve dynamically creating and executing scripts, which performance now hinges upon the responsiveness of Apple’s servers.

It seems that modifying the file through an editor modifies the inode causing it to be checked again but appending it with a redirect does not.

Comment: that was also my first thought when reading the headline (altough i didn't know what SIP is). almost all text editors (even sed -i) work with tmp files internally and replace the origin instead of changing it